# fetchedResultsController and Integer

Tags: xcode, xcode4, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I am updating a TableViewController from entity that contains two strings and one integer. The strings work correctly the integer does not. Here is my code;

```
     - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UsersCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[GolfersCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    Users *users = [_fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.firstName.text = users.firstName;
    cell.lastName.text = users.lastName;
        int i = [users.gendID intValue] ;
    cell.genID.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", i];

    [self configureCell:cell atIndexPath:indexPath];

    return cell;
}
```

Now this does work, commenting out the line "int i = [users.gendID intValue] ;" Leaving it in and stepping though the program this the error that it returns;

```
2012-04-30 16:49:02.369 My App [9757:fb03] -[Users gendID]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6b8a6c0
2012-04-30 16:49:02.373 My App[9757:fb03] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Users gendID]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6b8a6c0'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x16b0022 0x1841cd6 0x16b1cbd 0x1616ed0 0x1616cb2 0x3a6d 0xb5c54 0xb63ce 0xa1cbd 0xb06f1 0x59d21 0x16b1e42 0x2068679 0x2072579 0x1ff74f7 0x1ff93f6 0x1ff8ad0 0x168499e 0x161b640 0x15e74c6 0x15e6d84 0x15e6c9b 0x15997d8 0x159988a 0x1b626 0x28bd 0x2825)
terminate called throwing an exception(lldb)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like a typo to me. In your code the user property name is gendID while your cell's property is genID. "unrecognized selector sent to instance" means that there is no such method defined for that class. Verify that your Users class does indeed contain a method/property named "gendID".

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Lighforce's suggestion, you shouldn't be loading the cell content in two places.  After setting first name, last name, and genID, your code then calls configure cell at index path.  The problem may be in that method.  Put your setting code in one place or the other, but don't spead it between the two methods.